# WebStorm "Warning:File was not compiled because there is no a reference from tsconfig.json"

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2016.1.3 for an Angular 2 project with typescript. When I enable the ts compiler in WebStorm and modify a ts file (which should then be compiled) I get the following warning: `Warning:File was not compiled because there is no a reference from tsconfig.json` and the file is not compiled.

My project file/folder structure is close to the style guide recommended by Angular 2:

All my `ts` files are in a `script` folder. The root app is in that folder and every component has its own subfolder which contains one `ts` and one `html` file. Shared services etc are in a `Shared` subfolder.

My `tsconfig` looks like this and is in the project root folder (the parent folder of the `script` folder):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Except for the `ts` files directly in `script` all other in WebStorm opened and modified `ts` files result in the warning above and do not compile. In the typescript console in WebStorm the compiler says it was compiling the modified file (i.e. change detection seems to be working) but it does not emit a transpiled file. However, when WebStorm starts ALL `ts` files in all subfolders are correctly compiled. Also, if I use tsc manually or via gulp I get no issues and everything compiles as it should, which tells me that my `tsconfig` is OK.
I tried specifying my own scope in WebStorm's typescript compiler options. Made no difference. The `Track changes` option is on. I tried it with and without the `Resolve objects using tsconfig.json` option on. Made no difference.

I can't figure this thing out.
Has anybody else encountered - and hopefully fixed - this issue?

Comment: which 'Scope' are you using? Should be default value 'Project files'

Comment: Yes, that's what I had at first, since it is the default. That's when the issue arose initially. I changed the scope to see if it made a difference. It didn't.

Answer (score 1):

In case others run into this issue:

I think I have found what causes the issue. Some of my files had somewhat unusual spellings (in the typescript world). For example one of my services was spelled "ApiService.ts". After I changed this to "apiService.ts" the issue disappeared. Another was spelled "hhPager.component.ts". WebStorm didn't like that either. I now changed it to "pager.component.ts" and WebStorm relaxed and behaved.

I have brought it to JetBrain's attention and this is currently (July 8, 2016) a bug in their issue tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22290).

Comment: Thanks! I had to rename attach-magnify.ts to attachMagnify.ts and now intellij compiles. And thanks for making JetBrains aware of this issue :)

Comment: Just an observation, if `apiService.ts` works and `pager.component.ts` works why in the heck would `hhPager.component.ts` not work?  This infers that `apiService.component.ts` won't work... Two "h"s is not a typo...

I'm having this error and the above solution didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below block in tsconfig.json

```
  "files": [
    "typings/tsd.d.ts",
    "main.ts"
  ]
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Adding this block causes compilation errors. I don't have a typings/tsd.d.ts. Mine is typings/index.d.ts, which I used instead.

Comment: Webstorm is not resolving files linked to in files, tsc does